# PHP combine 2 mysql tables without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I have two mysql tables:

Table 1 (events):

```
|event_id|club_id|date|time|title|description|type|
```

Table 2 (events_participants):

```
|id|event_id|name|img|
```

This is how my php script looks like to fetch table one (events):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE club_id='$club'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

    $rows = [];       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Add all rows to an array
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Json encode the full array
    echo json_encode($rows);

} else {
    echo "0results";
}
```

The php code above for example produces the following result:

```
[
    {
        "event_id": "123456",
        "club_id": "1234567890",
        "organizer": "name",
        "date": "2016-04-24",
        "time": "08:00",
        "title": "Test Event",
        "description": "test...",
        "type": "Ride"
    }
]
```

How can I join the two tables so that it looks lik this for example:

```
[
     {
           "event_id": "123456",
           "club_id": "1234567890",
           "organizer": "name",
           "date": "2016-04-24",
           "time": "08:00",
           "title": "Test Event",
           "description": "test...",
           "type": "Ride",
           "name": "yourname",
           "img": "imageurl"
      }
]
```

Table 1 (events) has unique event_id rows, table 2 (events_participants) can have rows with duplicate event_id's.
So when there are duplicates in table 2 I'm looking for a result like this:

```
 [
    {
        "event_id": "123456",
        "club_id": "1234567890",
        "organizer": "name",
        "date": "2016-04-24",
        "time": "08:00",
        "title": "Test Event",
        "description": "test...",
        "type": "Ride",
        "name": [
            "yourname",
            "yourname2"
        ],
        "img": [
            "imageurl",
            "imageurl2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a result set that looks like this in SQL

```
    "name": [
        "yourname",
        "yourname2"
    ],
    "img": [
        "imageurl",
        "imageurl2"
    ]
```

At least, not easily. The closest you can do is:

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM events e INNER JOIN events_participants ep ON e.event_id = ep.eventid WHERE club_id= ? ORDER BY event_id";
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $club);
```

That will get you one row for each participant, with all the related values from the `events` table.

You should be using a method to access the database that supports variable binding, such as `mysqli` or `PDO`.